# python import site failed

Tags: python, import

When I execute python script, this problem occurs:

```
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
```

so I tried again with -v option, and I can get these messages:

```
'import site' failed; traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py", line 513, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py", line 495, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py", line 238, in addusersitepackages
    USER_BASE = env_base if env_base else joinuser("~", ".local")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site.py", line 225, in joinuser
    return os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(*args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 256, in expanduser
    userhome = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir
KeyError: 'getpwuid(): uid not found: 65530'
```

How can I deal with this situations?

Comment: I got this error when running a Python script as a systemd service with DynamicUser=yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it expects a user with id 65530 to exist on your system, but it doesn't. And it gets that id by calling `os.getuid()` which returns the current user id.

Perhaps the user you're running this as has been deleted or disabled in the meantime? Check `/etc/passwd` for clues.

---

Update in light of your comment: apparently `/etc/passwd` does not exist inside your chroot jail. Either you can try mapping it in, or you can set the `HOME` environment variable to something sensible, as the code for `expanduser` says:

```
    if 'HOME' not in os.environ:
        import pwd
        userhome = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_dir
    else:
        userhome = os.environ['HOME']
```

Comment: I execute this python script with chrooted.

Comment: I commented this block, and just set the `userhome = '/'` and this error disappears, many thanks :)

Comment: You hacked up the standard library of your system-wide Python installation, and in such a horrible way?! I advise to revert that right away before you make your system unusable. My answer contains two better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this issue. Little bit searching on the net, i got the fix. 
Check your environment variable PYTHONHOME.

Try to unset the PYTHONHOME and try. It worked for me.

(Ref: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/532383)

Answer (score 0):

If you get this ERROR from mod_wsgi on apache (in you app error log), the FIX is to add "home=/path/to/app" to your WSGIDaemonProcess directive in your wsgi.conf (it doesn't matter that much where you set the path to). For example--

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ckan_default display-name=ckan_default processes=2 threads=15 home=/usr/lib/ckan/default
```

Comment: The mod_wsgi case is different and not the same underlying problem. What mod_wsgi version are you using? That may have been the case for very old mod_wsgi versions, but am not sure that is true (can't remember) of the latest versions.