# how to resolve Import error in gurobi solver

Tags: gurobi, pyomo

i am using ubuntu system and trying to implement a simple optimization problem in pyomo using gurobi solver but came acroos following error

ERROR: Solver (gurobi) returned non-zero return code (1)
**: Solver log: ImportError: No module named site**

[    0.03] Pyomo Finished
ERROR: Unexpected exception while running model:
        Solver (gurobi) did not exit normally
errorcode: 1

i installed gurobi using conda
i added below lines in .bashrc file
 but still could'nt get the result
    `export GUROBI_HOME="/home/yash/anaconda3/pkgs/gurobi-8.1.1-py36_0"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"`

and i can import site from python so that is not the problem
[output errors which i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BvYl.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python import site failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672731/python-import-site-failed)

Comment: Could you add the option `--stream-solver` to your command? Do you have a Gurobi license?

Comment: i can import site from my python, so that's not the case.......and i cannot add --stream-solver to my pyomo command as it doesn't have that stream solver argument...and no i don't have gurobi license ..is it compulsory to run programs