# Trying to run file with pypy results in "'pypy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: python, pypy

I wanted to use pypy to make my python scripts faster.

I downloaded the zip file form the website and unzipped it in the C drive. I have python 3 (32bit) and Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable(x86) installed. I've added the path to the directory containing pypy3.exe to my PATH.

When I try to run a script, for example: pypy app.py I get a message saying "'pypy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use `pypy3` instead of `pypy` if you have downloaded pypy for python 3. This can be confirmed by looking inside the unzipped folder where you can see whether you have `pypy3.exe` or `pypy.exe`.

If that doesn't solve your issue, you need to ensure that the folder, where you unzipped **pypy**, is already in windows `PATH` environment variable. I am assuming you are using windows 10, in command line type the following:

`echo $PATH`

If you can't **pypy** folder in the `PATH`, add it using the command line:

`setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\location\of\pypy`

where you need to use the location of **pypy** folder. For example, if location of your pypy folder is `C:\pypy`, type the following command:

`setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\pypy`

You may need to restart your cmd for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I've run it with pypy3 instead of pypy and it seemed to work but then I got " 'import site' failed ". I've tried it on a file that just prints a string and it printed " 'import site' failed "and underneath printed the string

Comment: @Maria that error is unrelated to this question. To answer it we need to see the code and full error, therefore it should be a new question and can't be answered here. You can begin by checking this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/10672731/4901118, if it doesn't solve your problem you can consider asking a new question.